# File download not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, download

I have written this piece of code which is working perfect on Google Chrome and Opera but not working on Firefox

```
function onSaveJPG(url,n){
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = url;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = 'Image no '+n+'.jpeg' || url;
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}
```

What is wrong? please guide me.

Comment: Most of that is deprecated, most browsers now support the [event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: You have to append the save element to body

Comment: As a sidenote, to trigger the download, all you really have to do is `save.onclick();`

Answer (score 17):

This should work (I figured it out by looking through the FileSaver.js code):

```
function onSaveJPG(url,n){
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = url;
    save.download = 'Image no '+n+'.jpeg' || url;
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent(
                "click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                , false, false, false, false, 0, null
        );
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

(the main problem is that you need to use a MouseEvent type event for firefox rather than an Event. This code will also work on Chrome).