# unable to Save Canvas As An Image in local machine

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

how to save my canvas as an image with canvas.toDataURL():
here is my code:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  

window.location.href=image;
```

works fine. how can I change the name of downloaded file? it's coming just "download" and without extension. how i can save this canvas as png image in locally .Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an `a` element.
2. Set its `href` attribute to your url.
3. Set its `download` attribute to the desired filename.
4. Dispatch a `click` event on your element.

Or just see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047811/2302862).

Comment: Hi Siguza...Thanks a lot for your answer..can u plz suggest me how i can use this function with my exist code..actually i m little bit confuse becoz here i m using canvas.toDataURL ..so plz guide me..

Comment: The same function not working in mozila browser?Any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can check the demo [Click to Take a Screenshot & Download it!](http://codepen.io/Alexee/pen/QKPokb/) on codepen and read the [canvas2image.js](https://github.com/SuperAL/canvas2image) source code to deal with your problem, or just use the `canvas2image.js` to get your function done.

You can use it just like this,
filename is optional, default is Date.now():

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvasObj, width, height, type, fileName)
Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvasObj, width, height, fileName)
Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(canvasObj, width, height, fileName)
Canvas2Image.saveAsGIF(canvasObj, width, height, fileName)
Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(canvasObj, width, height, fileName)

Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvasObj, width, height, type)
Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvasObj, width, height)
Canvas2Image.convertToJPEG(canvasObj, width, height)
Canvas2Image.convertToGIF(canvasObj, width, height)
Canvas2Image.convertToBMP(canvasObj, width, height)
```